# JMeter: How to fetch values of hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

I tried extracting hidden element using CSS/JQuery extractor but that doesnot help.

Can XPath extractor be helpful for following expression:

```html
<input id="hdnBat" type="hidden" value="12345.8">
```

I have tried using following XPath Query:

```
//input[@type="hidden" ] [@id="hdnBat"]/@value
```

but that does not help.

And below is the error in JMeter log:

2016/07/20 13:03:33 ERROR - jmeter.util.XPathUtil: Type=Val=false Tol=false org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 64; Element type "link" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: You have a typo in your XPath expression: `hdnBat` vs. `hdnBalanceAmt`. Otherwise, the expression should work.

Comment: There was typo in question Markus, but thanks for notifying. However, this expression doesnot work.

Comment: The error message you added sounds more like you are trying to parse some broken HTML page as XML. Sax complains about a `link` element not being valid. This has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use With Normal Jquery or Javascript Using document.getElementById

In Javascript

var result = document.getElementById('hdnBat').val();

In Jquery

var result = $("#hdnBat").val();

You can try this